# Mongoose aggregate: Filtering based on Model.associated_Model.associated_Model.field returns wrong result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have three models `User`, `Profile`, and `Institution`.

> User

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "profiles",
  },
});
```

> Profile

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  institution: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "institutions",
  },
});
```

> Institution

```
const InstitutionSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

I am trying to get the list of users `WHERE` institution = institution_name:

```
User.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "profiles",
        let: { profiles_id: "$profile" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "institutions",
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $match: { name: institution_name },
                },
              ],
              as: "institution",
            },
          },
          { $unwind: "$institution" },
        ],
        as: "profile",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: "$profile" },
    {
      $project: {
        name: "$name",
        institution: "$profile.institution.name",
      },
    },
  ]);
```

For some strange reason, this is return the list of all users but it replaces the institution field with the filter value I used `institution_name`.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main mistakes in your query is that you are not performing joins based on some condition. In the first `$lookup` with `profiles` collection you are passing `profile` as `profiles_id` but not using it in the pipeline. Same is with the case of second `$lookup` with `institutions` as well.

Try this:

```js
const institution_name = "Institute 1";

db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "profiles",
            let: { profiles_id: "$profile" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        // Join condition.
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$profiles_id"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "institutions",
                        let: { institution_id: "$institution" },
                        pipeline: [
                            {
                                $match: {
                                    name: institution_name,
                                    // Join condition.
                                    $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$institution_id"] }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        as: "institution"
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$institution" },
            ],
            as: "profile",
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$profile" },
    {
        $project: {
            name: "$name",
            institution: "$profile.institution.name"
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b8"),
    "name" : "Dheemanth Bhat",
    "institution" : "Institute 1"
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b9"),
    "name" : "Ahmed Ghrib",
    "institution" : "Institute 1"
}
```

Test data:

`users` collection:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b8"),
    "name" : "Dheemanth Bhat",
    "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b5")
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b9"),
    "name" : "Ahmed Ghrib",
    "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b6")
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152ba"),
    "name" : "Alex Rider",
    "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b7")
}
```

`profiles` collection:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:49 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b5"),
    "institution" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b2")
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:49 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b6"),
    "institution" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b2")
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:49 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b7"),
    "institution" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b3")
},

/* 4 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:49 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b8"),
    "institution" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b4")
}
```

`institutions` collection:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:26 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b2"),
    "name" : "Institute 1"
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:26 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b3"),
    "name" : "Institute 2"
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:26 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b4"),
    "name" : "Institute 3"
}
```